# Jquery calender pop up color change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am creating a datepicker by using jquery.I am having problem in changing the color of the pop up calendar.
My code is:

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#checkin" ).datepicker({minDate : 0, dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
    $("#checkin").addClass("my-class");
    $("#checkout").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $( "#checkout" ).datepicker({minDate:0, dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});

    $( "#checkin" ).on("change",function(){
        onCheckin();

    });

});

function onCheckin(){
    if($("#checkin").val() !== ""){
        $("#checkout").removeAttr("disabled");
        var dateMin = $('#checkin').datepicker("getDate");
        var rMin = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(), dateMin.getDate() + 1);
        $("#checkout").datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(rMin));
    }else{
        $("#checkout").val("");
        $("#checkout").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
```

And html is:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-4'>
    <p>Checkin: <input type='text' id='checkin' ></p><br>
    </div>
    <div class='col-4'>
    <p>Checkout: <input type='text' id='checkout'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css is:

```
.my-class{
    background-color: #FF0F0F !important;
}
```

It changes the color of text area but i want to give  rigid background whenever the calendar pops up.I am new to web development.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calender popup hold a class `ui-datepicker`. So try with following css:

```
.ui-datepicker {
  background-color: #FF0F0F !important;
 }
```

OR:

```
$('.ui-datepicker').addClass('my-class');
```

And your Class is:

```
.my-class{
  background-color: #FF0F0F !important;
 }
```

Working snippet.

```js
$('#date').datepicker();
$('.ui-datepicker').addClass('my-class');
```

```css
.my-class{
    background-color: #FF0F0F !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='date'/>
```

Comment: I need to add (.ui-datepicker) class to my input element?

Comment: Glad to help.Validate answer for future. Happy Coding :)